# Search tables in Quandl

Tags: r, quandl

If I use this code (Windows/R Studio):

```
library(Quandl)
Quandl.search("Purchasing") # changed from ..
# sr=as.data.frame(search.results=Quandl.search("Purchasing"))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

I thought you don't need an Quandl-Key if you are just searching, am I wrong?

Comment: use `=` in data.frame not `<-`

Comment: Sorry, that does not work.

Comment: I meant inside the data frame. `as.data.frame(x = ...)`

Comment: I know, but unfortunately that does not change anything.

Comment: Regardless if it changes anything or not you still need to learn it correctly

Comment: Can you check whether `curl-ca-bundle.crt` file in present in your `/path/to/R/etc/x64` directory

Comment: I have found it, it's there.